# send instructions to a macbook terminal

Tags: python

I am somewhat new to python and I am trying to automate my database systems. Is there a way to have python send commands to a macbook terminal. Specifically I want to send this command to the terminal to backup the database.

Thanks in advance

```
backup.pg_dump --file 
"/Users/john/Dropbox/__Mag_bus/backups/analyze_stats_critical_files_only_2020-10- 
21.dump" --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "john" --no-password --verbose -- 
format=c --blobs --table  "__magazine_cover_prices" --table "__prospects" --table  
"__recommender_crosses" --table "__pricing_options" "analyze_stats"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.system()`.

```
from os import system
system("""backup.pg_dump --file 
"/Users/john/Dropbox/__Mag_bus/backups/analyze_stats_critical_files_only_2020-10- 
21.dump" --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "john" --no-password --verbose -- 
format=c --blobs --table  "__magazine_cover_prices" --table "__prospects" --table  
"__recommender_crosses" --table "__pricing_options" "analyze_stats" """)
```

Comment: No, don't use `os.system`. Use `subprocess`.

Comment: @chepner what are the advantages?

Comment: @chepner I'm not familiar with subprocess

Comment: It's in the standard library; look it up.